# Python - Problem returning True/False to class properties from class method

Tags: python, class, class-method

I have a class as below which within the `__init__` method I am trying to assign a True/False value to a class property using a class method.

```
class Sensor:

    def __init__(self, json_data):
        self.sensor_eui = json_data['end_device_ids']['dev_eui']
        self.reading1 = json_data['uplink_message']['decoded_payload']['temperature']
        self.reading2 = json_data['uplink_message']['decoded_payload']['humidity']
        self.tolerance_exceeded = self.tolerance_check

   def tolerance_check(self):
        sql = f"SELECT DefaultLowerLimit, DefaultUpperLimit FROM [dbo].[IoT_Sensors] WHERE 
              DeviceID = '{self.sensor_eui}'"
        results = exec_sql(sql)

        if (self.reading1 > int(results[0])) and (self.reading1 < int(results[1])):
            return False
        return True
```

The issue is, when trying to troubleshoot this and logging the objects to the console, instead of returning True or False as the assigned value of 'tolerance_exceeded' it returns the method and object:

```
logging.info(f'Tolerance Exceeded: {sensor.tolerance_exceeded}')
```

logs in the console as below:

```
[2022-10-26T12:08:08.025Z] Tolerance Exceeded: <bound method Sensor.tolerance_check of <__app__.IoT_Data-Handler.classes.Sensor object at 0x000001C834D45BE0>>
```

So what is going on here?  I have not been coding long, but when I have done something similar in the past (assigning a string value from an API), it worked fine.  This is for an Azure Function, but I cannot see how that would impact what I am trying to achieve.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `self.tolerance_check` to `self.tolerance_check()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that instead of calling the function you assign it. In order to call the function you have to add the parenthesis.

```py
class Sensor:

    def __init__(self, json_data):
        self.sensor_eui = json_data['end_device_ids']['dev_eui']
        self.reading1 = json_data['uplink_message']['decoded_payload']['temperature']
        self.reading2 = json_data['uplink_message']['decoded_payload']['humidity']
        # Calling tolerance_check and assigning return value to tolerance_exceeded
        self.tolerance_exceeded = self.tolerance_check()
```

Comment: That was it - thanks.  Just needed another pair of eyes on it.  Thanks again!